# Force Close error description

Tags: android

I've released an application to some people for testing. Some of them are reporting that it works fine, while other say that they are getting Force Close error on the first run. How can I get the error description that happens, so I can fix it?

Comment: You should provide more informations, for example versions of system hat are using people which are getting forced close.

Comment: I've gotten the error log from some users, and this is the error: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: FTSwords, db=/data/data/com.android.myapp/databases/words

Answer (score 1):

For now, ask users to install any logcat reading app and send you the stacktrace, if they're running Android 4.0 or below.

In future updates, integrate a library like [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) that can automatically send you error reports.

Answer (score 0):

Ask a selection of your users to install [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat), and to send the logs to you when the problem occurs. After all, assuming they're all suffering from the same problem, you only really need a single user to send you the logs so that you can get a call stack to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

You can try **[Application Crash Report](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)** for Android.

Second most suitable for error logging **[BugSense](http://bugsense.com/)**. It upload the error message on dashboard immediately.

Third I have example on github to send the error trace on to developer email.

https://github.com/ajaysaini-sgvu/CrashReport